# Can I use a general purpose Microcontroller to charge a lithium battery

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

This is new hardware hacking for me. I get hat there are charger IC’s, but I Wanted to know if I could program a standard Atmega or PIC microcontroller to help me learn how to charge a battery?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please quickly realise that this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows that you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which your post doesn't, I'm afraid. Please revise your question showing your work and findings so far, in considerable detail. Or delete the question if Internet searches give you your answer anyway. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Comment: @TonyM I understand that, I just want facts as to whether it is possible, not free consultation.

Comment: Sorry Iam, you've asked a big question that will require far, far more effort and time to answer than the few seconds it took you to write your couple of lines. That's the opposite of how the site works, I'm afraid - this isn't Facebook for arguing on and the people who can help you are completely unpaid and voluntary. Please read my earlier comment and seriously improve the quality of your question to *attract* interest and to show thinking for people to guide. Look at other questions to see what gets good results here. No more angry comments please and I wish you well.

Comment: You could program the micro as a battery charger in conjunction with some other bits and bobs. Whether that helps you learn though I can't say.

Comment: Iam- genuine advice - responses like your one to TonyM, who gave you good advice, will cause you more harm than good and when people persist in that vein they usually end up leaving the site either voluntarily or 'with assistance'. This is a shame as if people are prepared to follow guidance the site is a real goldmine and learning how to ask good questions is valuable in many other areas. | The answer to your question is "yes". Or even "Of course'. That's a useless answer but the question does not encourage much better ones. -> See brief answr below:
...

Comment: Almost any uC can be used to measure and control voltage and current and so can be used to implement a charger. Having a few ADCs helps heaps. Having a DAC also may help but is not necessary.

Comment: You *could* do what you say, but like all beginners tiny mistakes will not charge or overcharge the batteries. Do NOT experiment with lithium batteries until you are good with lead-acid batteries. Lithium batteries can and will explode if over charged.

Answer (score 2):

Almost any uC can be used to measure and control voltage and current and so can be used to implement a charger. Having a few ADCs helps heaps. Having a DAC also may help but is not necessary.

Specifying what you want to achieve in more detail and looking at some of the many solutions on the web will help your understanding.

To charge say a 1 cell LiIon battery you need > 4.2V source voltage - say 5V, a means of measuring battery voltage and curent in and a means of controlling current in.
Voltage can be measured with an ADC channel.
Current can be measured with a sense resistor and an ADC (with limits on accuracy - no details here).
Current can be controlled with PWM from a digital output pin.

So many uC's can achieve the task. Any eg Arduino running on 5V can do this.